# Override Company Address Telephone field Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, backend, magento2.4.4

In My Account > Address Book. We have Default address & Company Address section.
In Company address, telephone is getting saved as (4-03)9038-383. I want to save it in numbers only i.e. 4039038383

Can someone suggest me how to do the same using plugin.

Thanks,
Rashi

Comment: You want to save telephone filed value while save the company on backend ? Correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an event in your custom module **`app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml`**

```
<event name="customer_address_save_before">
     <observer name="telephone_no_customer_address_model_save_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Customer\ModelSaveBefore"/>
</event>
```

Create **`ModelSaveBefore.php`** inside **`Vendor\Module\Observer\Customer`**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ModelSaveBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerFactory;

    public function __construct(CustomerFactory $customerFactory)
    {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }
    
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        $telephone = $customerAddress->getTelephone();
        $customerAddress->setTelephone(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $telephone));
    }
}
```

**Run commands accordingly and get your work done**

**UPDATE: Using Plugin**

Add in `etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\ModelSaveBefore">
        <plugin name="telephone_no_customer_address_model_save_before" type="Magento\Customer\Observer\BeforeAddressSaveObserver" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\ModelSaveBefore.php`

And try below code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Observer\BeforeAddressSaveObserver

class ModelSaveBefore 
{
    public function beforeExecute(BeforeAddressSaveObserver $subject, $result)
    {
        $customerAddress = $result->getCustomerAddress();
        $telephone = $customerAddress->getTelephone();
        $customerAddress->setTelephone(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $telephone));
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arun, Thanks for the input but I want to utilise plugin only for this action. Can you guide me on this using plugin? Also, this is required for company address only.

Comment: can you please look into my query asap?

Comment: Please check the updated ans

Comment: Arun- This is for customer but I want to do the same for Company only i.e. when from the backend I will create a new company & click on save. At that time,I want to utilise this logic before save

Comment: @RashiGoyal Magento have only two options in admin for address by default. Can you please share the screenshot?

Comment: At the backend, Navigate to Customers > Companies > Add New Company > Then on Save button I have call before plugin i.e to save Company Legal Address. IS this useful for you? or screenshot required

Comment: Rashi I think you are using third party extension or custom module for Customer > Companies. Because Magento doesn't have default option for that I think you have to look into the module from where the company address is created and create a module for that.